# TChart quality issue

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-xe5, teechart

We were using Delphi 2010 with the full VCL edition of TeeChart this worked fine

We have now updated to Delphi XE 5 with the latest version of TeeChart and the quality of the charts is now worse

Please see the image [here](http://www.stcenergy-online.com/dev/narrow.png)

2 bars which were seperate are now merged into 1 bar

If I make the charts wider which is not an option it looks better but still not as good as before

Please see [here](http://www.stcenergy-online.com/dev/wide.png)

Has anyone come across any issue like this?

The projects are [here](http://www.stcenergy-online.com/dev/chartproblem.zip) for Delphi XE5 and [here](http://www.stcenergy-online.com/dev/delphi2010chart.zip) for Delphi 2010

The search paths may need modifying

Cheers

Paul

Comment: I'm sure you will get an answer at the vendors forum. They are very responsive.

Comment: thanks I found that after I posted here although they do suggest posting here as well :)

Comment: Looks like a line-smoothing or anti-aliasing issue. I seem to recall these were not default settings in D2010. I suspect you probably just want to turn off anti-aliasing.

Comment: How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 3):

The issue might be because of the anti-aliasing function being turned on by default in the newer versions of TChart(!).
We had the same issue with a line series graph.
After writing to the vendor (Steema) they came up with the following solution:

```
Chart1.Canvas := TTeeCanvas3D.Create; //Disable GDI+ to prevent smooth drawing of the graph.
```

I don't get why we have to switch off drawing with GDI+ as - to my knowledge - GDI+ can also be used without anti-alias.
Anyway, our graphs now behave like the previous versions of the TChart, which is what we want.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try that tomorrow although I am not using 3d I assume I would just do tteecanvas.create?

Not at a computer at the moment so I can't check

Comment: This didnt work :( I am using a bar chart so not sure if thats why this didnt work

Comment: @Paul What TeeChart version were you using with Delphi 2010?

Answer (score 1):

I was also hating the "new" anti-aliased charts that are blurry and *slow*.
It's pretty easy to fix, when you know where to search for.
Double-click on chart, then go to 3D -> Render -> select GDI instead of GDI+

If you look "behind the scenes" into DFM file you can see the change:
Crisp and fast graph (as in 2010): DefaultCanvas = 'TTeeCanvas3D'
Blurry and slow graph (as in XE5): DefaultCanvas = 'TGDIPlusCanvas'

[chart settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Lhl.png)

Hope this helps.

Some kind of a clumsy runtime workaround was found here, that is also working:
http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15078